# SQL where statement after update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to update the max dog id value into the `dogsID` column (in the `DOGS` table) where `dogs.breed` is 'pitbull' by getting the `MAX` value of the `dogID` column in the `doggy_table`.

How can I accomplish this update statement?

I need a where statement at the end, but this is not proper syntax

```
update DOGS(dogsID)
values ( (SELECT MAX(dogID) as dogID
          FROM doggy_table)
       )
where [DOGS].[BREED] = 'pitbull'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to do an *update* statement?

```
UPDATE dogs 
SET    dogsid = (SELECT Max(dogid) AS dogID 
                 FROM   doggy_table) 
WHERE  [dogs].[breed] = 'pitbull'
```